# How to send requests to Xbox Live Restful API?

Tags: xbox, xbox-live

I want to send request to Profiles URIs and People URIs of Xbox Live Restful API. I can't understand the Authorization part of these two interfaces.

- [POST (/users/batch/profile/settings)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/xbox-live-rest/uri/profilev2/uri-usersbatchprofilesettingspost) page said only a normal auth token and claims are needed. How to generate the auth token and what's the claims are?

I use follow command to send request to `POST (/users/batch/profile/settings)`:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://profile.xboxlive.com/users/batch/profile/settings \
  -H 'Signature: xxxx' \
  -H 'Authorization: XBL3.0 x=xxxx' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'x-xbl-contract-version: 2' \
  -d '{
    "userIds": [
        "xxxx"
    ],
    "settings": [
        "AppDisplayName",
        "GameDisplayName",
        "Gametag",
        "AppDisplayPicRaw",
        "GameDisplayPicRaw",
        "AccountTier",
        "TenureLevel",
        "Gamescore"
    ]   
}'
```

The Xbox Live Restful API return 403.

- [GET (/users/{ownerId}/people)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/xbox-live-rest/uri/people/uri-usersowneridpeopleget) page said XUID authorization is needed and also have a Authorization Header. Where to place the XUID?

I use follow command to send request to `GET (/users/{ownerId}/people)`:

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://social.xboxlive.com/users/xuid(xxxx)/people' \
  -H 'Signature: xxxx' \
  -H 'Authorization: XBL3.0 x=xxxx'
```

It also return 403.

Are there some demos to show how to call the Xbox Live Restful API?

After [some search](https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-api/blob/master/InProgressSamples/Kits/LiveTK/HttpCall.cpp#L426), We should pass `Signature` and `Authorization` in the headers of requests. We can get `Signature` and `Authorization` from [`GetTokenAndSignatureAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xbox.services.system.xboxliveuser.gettokenandsignatureasync?view=xboxlive-dotnet-2017.11.20171204.01) and the claims and XUID encoded in the `Authorization`, But it's still return 403.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @JeffThomas I have wroten my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have follow the [`authenticate`](https://github.com/OpenXbox/xbox-webapi-python/blob/master/xbox/webapi/authentication/manager.py#L164) of [`xbox-webapi-python`](https://github.com/OpenXbox/xbox-webapi-python) to get the `Authorization` header(`XBL3.0 x=<uhs>,<xsts>`). Just add `Authorization` to each Xbox Live API request beside other required headers, You can get correcttly response.

The value of `Authorization` also can get by [`getTokenAndSignatureAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xbox.services.system.xboxliveuser.gettokenandsignatureasync?view=xboxlive-dotnet-2017.11.20171204.01). This value is apply to all Xbox API endpoint.

Comment: I am doing the same in my code, still getting 403 in that case. When i pass the "Authorization" header captured from Windows 10 (xbox overlay), the request succeeds though