# How to correctly populate Authentication request header for Xbox Live REST APIs?

Tags: rest, web-applications, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api, xbox

I want to use the [Xbox Services REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/reference/live/rest/uri/atoc-xboxlivews-reference-uris), particularly one of the [achievement APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/reference/live/rest/uri/achievements/uri-usersxuidachievementsscidachievementidget) for my very first web application that I'm building. In order to use any of these APIs, I have to include a required Authorization request header in every one of my requests. This request header must be a string populated with the following information:

> Authentication credentials for HTTP authentication. Example value: "XBL3.0 x=<userhash>;<token>".

However, I'm unsure of how to properly supply the missing <userhash> and <token> expected here. I found a promising lead in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853445/how-to-send-requests-to-xbox-live-restful-api) asked where one of the answers suggested using "[authenticate](https://github.com/OpenXbox/xbox-webapi-python/blob/master/xbox/webapi/authentication/manager.py#L164) of the [xbox-webapi-python](https://github.com/OpenXbox/xbox-webapi-python) to get the Authorization header". I have downloaded this repository and have access to the aforementioned script. However, I'm having trouble figuring out what I specifically need to do with it to get the information I need.

Can anyone provide some guidance here or share another way to collect this header information? I'm new to python and web development, FYI!

Thanks!