# I want to send a request to https://emerald.xboxservices.com I already have 2 of the 4 header values I need but can't find how to get the other 2

Tags: rest, ms-access, xbox

## SAMPLE REQUEST

```
GET /xboxcomfd/buddypass/Offers HTTP/2
Host: emerald.xboxservices.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0
Accept: /
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Prefer: safe
Referer: https://www.xbox.com/
authorization: XBL3.0 x={uhs};{xstsToken}
ms-cv: {ms-cv}
x-ms-api-version: 1.0
x-s2s-authorization: Bearer {token}
Origin: https://www.xbox.com/
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
TE: trailers
```

I can't find the values of {token} in x-s2s-authorization and {ms-cv} idk how to get that. I have already got the {uhs} and {xstsToken}

I have tried looking every but can't find out how to do this

Comment: Why MS-Access tag? What language is this code? Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853445/how-to-send-requests-to-xbox-live-restful-api